# Is the Lego Duplo Track System being discontinued?

Tags: duplo, discontinued, tracks

Our child recently got the [Duplo train starter set 10507](https://brickset.com/sets/10507-1/My-First-Train-Set) as a gift. The box indicates an extension pack with more tracks, so I was confident our child would be able to extend the (sorry) somewhat boring little circle out of 12 curved track parts from 10507.

On the official Lego website, however, I am seeing now that the only two Duplo train sets still being offered now are the aforementioned 10507, as well as [10508, the huge Deluxe Train Set](https://brickset.com/sets/10508-1/Deluxe-Train-Set), as well as [10810, a push-train](https://brickset.com/sets/10810-1/Push-Train).

With 10507 and 10508 having appeared in 2013, only 10810 having been released in 2016 (and this set being rather "simple" - no motor, no switches, also just one straight track per set), and the latest [tracks pack, 10506](https://brickset.com/sets/10506-1/Train-Accessory-Set), not even available any more in the official store ... **does this mean I should start hoarding compatible Duplo tracks now, before I also can't get any on Amazon and in toy stores, either?**

*Note that I'm not asking whether anyone can see the future. I'm asking whether TLC has made any public announcements on their future plans for Duplo railroads, or whether there are at least any known sales numbers for Duplo railroad sets that indicate they are/are not a commercial failure these days.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It hasn't been officially announced yet, but there are at least four large LEGO DUPLO train sets coming this summer. This includes two extension train track packs with straight tracks, curved tracks, switches, bridges, and train crossings. The two full train sets will include more of the same tracks. The set numbers for the extension packs are #10872 and #10882, and the new train sets are #10874 and #10875. The official set names are prices are yet unknown. I would suggest to wait until the summer, unless you can get the older sets for a very good price.

Comment: Excellent, that sounds promising. Where does one learn about that kind of information? Only as/via an "insider"?

Comment: LEGO fan sites, forums, and social-media groups are good sources of early info on upcoming sets. There is not one source, but coming from all over the place; LEGO themselves through their own channels (some intentional, some accidental), LEGO partners, LEGO retailers, news channels, insider info, etc. You can always ask here, and if some info is known already, someone will let you know. Or, you can just wait until LEGO announces the new sets officially. The big releases with a wide variety of sets are at the beginning of the year, and in the summer, with a few smaller releases in between.